# "material-table" - How to add more rows per page and fix rendering - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I am trying to apply more rows per page to my table from `material table`. Until now I found out that you can add an array with the wishful rows per page ex. `rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, 50, 100]}`
, but my problem is when I apply the row of 100 the table extends to a blank one. ( I receive at the moment only 24 rows (documents) from the backend ) So basically it has to be limited to the data that I have. Can someone give me a hand? Thank you

```
 divideItems = () => {

        let startIndex = ((parseInt(this.state.activePaginationTab) + 1) * this.state.rowsPerPage) - this.state.rowsPerPage;
        let endIndex = (parseInt(this.state.activePaginationTab) + 1) * this.state.rowsPerPage - 1;
        let tabItems = [];

        for (let i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
            if (this.state.items[i]) {
                tabItems.push(this.state.items[i]);
            }
        }


        this.setState({
            tabItems
        }, () => {

        });

    }
    getNewIndex = (event, page) => {
        this.setState({
            activePaginationTab: page
        }, () => { this.divideItems() })
        // this.divideItems(page)


    };

    handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {

        this.setState({
            rowsPerPage: event.target.value
        }, () => {
            this.divideItems();
        })
    }
```

```
render() {
  components={{
              Pagination: props => (
                  <TablePagination
                      {...props}
                      rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, 50,100]}
                      rowsPerPage={this.state.rowsPerPage}
                      count={this.state.items.length}
                      />
    ),
```

Comment: you can accept my answer, if you think it's useful :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props) you can use emptyRowsWhenPaging and set it to false in the options.

Comment: Thanks mate didn't saw that prop in the documentation

Comment: It should be more visibel. I'll talk to the maintainer.

Comment: yeah it will be a good idea . Do you know an property to change the default view of the rows . At deafault is set to 5 , but is there some prop that can be set to 10 for ex. ?

Comment: There is the pageSize option.

Comment: Yeah just found it also thank you . You made my day

Answer (score 21):

We can add rows per page and further pagination options as

```
   <MaterialTable
      title=""
      columns={myColumns}
      data={myData}      
      options={{
        paging:true,
        pageSize:6,       // make initial page size
        emptyRowsWhenPaging: false,   // To avoid of having empty rows
        pageSizeOptions:[6,12,20,50],    // rows selection options
      }}
    />
```

**Update 2023**

As per the comments by Zolbayar and Jeremy `options.pageSizeOptions` is replaced with `muiTablePaginationProps.rowsPerPageOptions`. See [latest-docs](https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/pagination#customize-pagination)

```
<MaterialReactTable
  columns={columns}
  data={data}
  muiTablePaginationProps={{
    rowsPerPageOptions: [5, 10],
    showFirstButton: false,
    showLastButton: false,
  }}
/>
```

Comment: This does not work in material-react-table v1.14.0

Comment: Ok as it's an old answer it might not for the new versions. Please add midifications to this answer or add yours to keep this thread up-to-date.

Comment: `options.pageSizeOptions` is replaced with `muiTablePaginationProps.rowsPerPageOptions`. See https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/pagination#customize-pagination

Answer (score 5):

Add these attribute in the options section of the material table

```
    pageSize:10
    pageSizeOptions:[10,20,30]
```

- **PageSize:** Number of rows that would be rendered on every page
- **pageSizeOptions:** Page size options that could be selected by user

  ```
   options={{
       pageSize:10,
       pageSizeOptions:[10,20,30],
  ```

  }}